# Web Development | 404 HTML Coding

Tags: php

I made a customized 404 error page that if the user request or go to an invalid page, the 404 page will show up.

How can I make the 404 Page to print what does the user requested to my website?

Example: `http://example.com/stackoverflowisamazing.php`

Page print:

> Error: The requested page '*stackoverflowisamazing.php*' couldn't find in our database. Please try again later.

Comment: Try `$url = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";`

Comment: HINT: You have to set your server

Comment: Doesnt it also enable xss ?
It would just be good practice to display the 404 page with links to the site-map or a link to the homepage.

Comment: How do I implement it on the .php page? Please help me, and btw Kudos to you sir!

Comment: http://kirkniverba.netne.net/ Here's my website, please visit it and please help me :(

Comment: Well, I've been on a "not-so-long" vacation but I managed to find a solution on this using javaScript, by the way, thanks for all of you for helping me out ;) Thanks!